# Can't disconnect bones

Tags: rigging, bones

So, i'm making a jumpscare, and i need to get that puppet out of the character's arm. But when i try doing so, this happens;

https://i.gyazo.com/883e8c5200d774a1b844697df19ddf46.gif

The rig somehow made an IK rig by itself or something. I have nothing to do with those yellow bones. How do i fix this?

Comment: The title suggest a different problem, do you want to get rid of the IK or keep it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your mesh is set up but you can try going into Edit mode and selecting the bone that you want to be separated. Then, go into the Bone panel and under the Relations section, remove the parent and uncheck Connected.